# How to update tile notification for windows phone 8 in webservice?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I develop an app which getting the number of invoice in webservice and it will be updated in the tile notification every 2 minutes. The invoice number will be updated in count variable at scheduledAgent.cs . Any idea?

In main page

```
ServiceReference1.WebServiceSoapClient test = new ServiceReference1.WebServiceSoapClient();

test.ReadTotalOutstandingInvoiceCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.ReadTotalOutstandingInvoiceCompletedEventArgs>(serviceClient);

test.ReadTotalOutstandingInvoiceAsync();


private void serviceClient(object sender, ReadTotalOutstandingInvoiceCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
         PeriodicTask p = new PeriodicTask("jj");

         p.Description = "Don't push the red button";

         ScheduledActionService.Add(p);

         ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(p.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
     }

     catch(Exception ex)
     {

     }
}
```

In ScheduledAgent.cs

```
 protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
    {
         //TODO: Add code to perform your task in background
         ShellTile t = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();

         StandardTileData d = new StandardTileData()
         {
             Title = "asdasdad",

             BackTitle = "cxvxvxvxcv",

             Count = 42,

             BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("dog.jpg", UriKind.Relative),

             BackgroundImage = new Uri("untitled.png", UriKind.Relative)
         };
             t.Update(d);

             NotifyComplete();

    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to use a periodic task that updates the tile every two minutes? "The PeriodicTask runs approximately every 30 minutes, for about 25 seconds." -http://jesseliberty.com/2011/10/05/background-agents/

Comment: Thx @robertftw. Shall it work with webservice update variable count of tile notification in every 2 minute?

Comment: If you want to update the tile count every two min you have to have a server that pushes out a notification. Not something I would recommend though.

Comment: My app is like message notification, skpe notification on the tile of windows phone.